# Get list of streets for selected town

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to get list of all streets in selected town ( I have DropDownList on my page with cities in my country, when user select some town to fill another DropDownList with streets in that town ) ? Also, can I get name of that part of town for selected street ?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, but you're probably looking for a downloadable list or API:

http://www.melissadata.com/lookups/zipstreet.asp